# Detect swipe right on iphone home screen programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak, theos, spotlight

I'm creating a jailbreak tweak for iphone (running iOS 7) using theos.

I really new to this and you can consider this as my first tweak!

**What I want? :**

1. Check if its the 1st home screen
2. **IF** 1st screen then, Detect for Swipe right gesture
3. Do Something on Swipe right

> Just like how spotlight for ios 6 and below worked.

**My Code:**

```
#import <SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h>

%hook SpringBoard

-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(id)application {
    %orig;

   //Check if its the 1st home screen
   //Detect for Swipe right gesture
   //Do Something on Swipe right
}

%end
```

I can use touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded. But how do I implement the gesture?

Am I missing any imports?

Comment: I'm not familiar with jailbreaking or theos, but can you just use a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: But how do i check if its the FIRST home screen?

Comment: As I said, I'm not familiar with jail breaking or theos.  In non-jail broken apps, you're never on the home screen.  I can't answer that part of your question.